# Tee requests with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I'm using HAProxy to loadbalance TCP service. I would like to "tee" the same request to a different cluster (dev instance).

Does HAProxy have the "tee" feature?

The dev, prod clusters and the HAProxy are different subnets, so I can't use the "tee" feature in `iptables`.

Answer (score 2):

I have not done this myself but if you don't need real-time copying you could use tcpdump to capture the traffic and [wireplay](https://code.google.com/p/wireplay/) to send it to the dev instance.

Edit: the answer is no.

Comment: tcpdump is not going to scale for me. I have ~30 GB data per day, and I need it realtime. Thanks for your comment.